# ¿How does the Blender User achieve a shortcut for Custom Operator in Pose Mode?

Tags: python, shortcut

**¿How does the Blender User achieve a shortcut for custom operator in Pose Mode?**

Problem

---

An operator was created and is functional for the past hour or so.  A Shortcut Key was desired.  The operator name appears in [pose mode] menu Pose.  Operator use with the mouse is successful. Attempt is made to create short cut with the Add Shortcut menu depicted below. Key Binding does not appear which is a problem.  Key Binding = Shortcut in this description.

Other investigations, attempts and successes

---

Key binding in [object mode] is successful. Operator use is successful in menus.  Specials Menu and Python Console and Python dir command.

Key Binding attempted in [Pose Mode] creates Key Binding in [Object Mode]

[image]
The image above shows a simple operator template supplied by Blender for the text editor and then modified.

Click image to see larger original size.

[image]

Add Shortcut depicted in the image above.

[image]

User Preference image above.

[image]

Object Mode with Short Cut. Image above.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Manually employ User preferences will do the job.  Settings below.  This is not the only method.   Complications will be in a different question.

[image]